fix cell output size in vscode jupyter for output of type text/html
I am using jupyter notebook in vscode and have a big dataframe. I would like to display the whole dataframe but make it scrollable horizontally and vertically.
I have changed the pandas display options with :
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None

This results in rendering like this :
rendering of dataframe
As seen in above image, I have the horizontal scroll but not vertical.
In vscode, there is an option to limit no of lines in text/plain but not in text/html.(these are two types of cell output format)
option to change max output size in text/plain
any suggestion on how can I set a vertical line limit on text/html output?
Summary of things I have tried till now :
I have changed the pandas display options with :
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None

and updated Max Output Size option in vscode settings to 30.
